# What is the word of Spanish or Portuguese origin starting with "a" and meaning enthusiast?

Tags: loanwords, spanish

There is a word starting with "a" (along the lines of "afinados") meaning [enthusiast](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enthusiast), [connoisseur](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/connoisseur#Noun) or [fan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fan#Etymology_2_2). What is it?

Comment: How funny. was going to sugggest googling for "afinado" and have google say "Did you mean aficionado" - but that of course only works if the word you enter does not already exist ;))

Comment: @mplungjan 3: you can always assume I have googled before asking such a question. It goes without saying.

Comment: It's always reassuring to know OP has already attempted to google an answer before posting a question. On the downside, the rest of us can't just pick up a few easy rep points by googling ourselves... :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Aficionado](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aficionado)?

> : a person who likes, knows about, and appreciates a usually fervently pursued interest or activity : devotee

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks! I have now increased the world's knowledge by adding it to Wiktionary (as a synomym of enthusiast).

Comment: I am aware of the meaning of *aficionado* in English as a loan from Spanish. However, *aficionado* in Spanish has a different nuance; it conveys a very clear sense of amateurism. In Spanish, *aficionado* does not mean being an enthusiastic fan of something; it has a much softer and less "raving" edge to it.